# Why do you need to use this "f" with dynamic http responses in django?

Tags: django, http, url, view, httpresponse

For example:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def view(request, something):
    return HttpResponse(f' {something} ')
```

I've found many examples like this one, but no explanation of what the 'f' means in 'HttpResponse(**f**' {something} '), or why is it necessary. It's not used when you don't utilize a captured value from the url.

Comment: it is called [`f-string`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/) notation

Answer (score 0):

Using **f-string** you can make dynamic strings easily.

Suppose You have variables as `age = 24`, `name = Mateo`. You want to return the string as My Name is **Mateo** and age is **24**.
For a single user, you can hardcore this program, but for multiple users, you have to go dynamically.

Here age is an integer and name is a string. Normally for making a normal sentence you have to **typecast integer** value **to string** name then you can concatenate the two strings. But in **f-string** you don't need to typecast any value python does it for you.

Comment: Really apreciatte the insight, I would upvote the answer if I could lol